# Spring Cloud Config Eureka server discovery and zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to setup a simple microservice architecture based on Spring functionalities. I have 3 simple microservices as starting point:
1 Configuration Server (Spring cloud config)
2 Discovery Server (eureka server)
3 Gateway Zuul

I configure the services so that the discovery server store all the .properties file, it register itself to the discovery server so all other services retrieve the .properties file accessing the discovery not via static url but via eureka server.

My problem is, eureka-server has in the bootstrap.properties file the static url of the discovery and it can retrieve the file succesfully but the gateway didn't retrieve the file from the server. I have a the following error:

```
2020-03-24 16:49:32.287  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://host.docker.internal:8081/. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-03-24 16:49:32.289  WARN 43460 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://host.docker.internal:8081/gateway/default": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

My configuration for the services is the following:

**config**:

- application.properties:

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=config

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///${user.home}/application-config

eureka.client.region = default
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds = 5
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8082/eureka/
```

- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**discovery**:

- bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.name=discovery
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8081
```

- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**gateway**:

- bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.name=gateway
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=config
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8082/eureka/
```

- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the 2 files .properties stored in /application-config are the following

- discovery.properties

```
spring.application.name=discovery
server.port=8082

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8082/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

- gateway.properties

```
spring.application.name=gateway
server.port=8080

eureka.client.region = default
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds = 5

zuul.routes.book-service.path=/book-service/**
zuul.routes.book-service.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
hystrix.command.book-service.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000

zuul.routes.rating-service.path=/rating-service/**
zuul.routes.rating-service.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
hystrix.command.rating-service.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000

zuul.routes.discovery.path=/discovery/**
zuul.routes.discovery.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
zuul.routes.discovery.url=http://localhost:8082
hystrix.command.discovery.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000
```

The strange thing is that if after I start everything I try to access the gateway file from the browser calling http://host.docker.internal:8081/gateway/default I can retrieve the file but when the gateway starts he tries to retrieve the same file and It gaves my the error above:

```
2020-03-24 16:49:22.236  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://host.docker.internal:8081/
2020-03-24 16:49:32.287  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://host.docker.internal:8081/. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-03-24 16:49:32.289  WARN 43460 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://host.docker.internal:8081/gateway/default": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2020-03-24 16:49:32.298  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.gateway.GatewayApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-24 16:49:33.223  WARN 43460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-03-24 16:49:33.249  WARN 43460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-03-24 16:49:33.468  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0021ee62-0366-3a59-86e9-68f6b99d3e59
2020-03-24 16:49:34.550  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-24 16:49:34.562  INFO 43460 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If someone has my same problem I found the solution. It was due to my host file. I changed it once to fit with a VPN I worked and it map my ip with an ip I can't reach without the VPN on. Once I comment the file host everything works